# Can't append new data to existing document in MongoDB colllection

Tags: php, mongodb

I tried to enter weight and ink fields with relevant data using php. But this gives "something wrong" error message. What i want to do is i want to add weight and ink fields to chosen existing mongoDB document

```
$insRec       = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$insRec->update(['id'=>new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($b['$oid'])],['$push' =>['ink' =>$ink, 'weight'=>$weight]], ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false]);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('sampledb.style', $insRec, $writeConcern);
print_r($result);
   if($result->getModifiedCount()){
       echo "OK";
    }else{
            echo "Something Wrong";
```

Comment: $b['$oid']) gives the relevant object id correctly. Only problem is appending isn't work

Comment: Can you 'find the records with the same query filter, i.e. the query part is definitely OK? Is there anything in the database logs?

Comment: You are missing the name of the array where you like to insert ink and weight document. Should be like `['$push' => [arrayname =>['ink' =>$ink, 'weight'=>$weight]]]`. On side note try printing the error that you get back from mongo instead of some generic error.

Comment: Would there be an error? I guessed it was just 'didn't match anything'